# Google maps direction icon's

Tags: google-maps-api-3

On Google Maps when displaying driving directions there are direction icons located on the left (roundabout, left arrow, right arrow etc), I've searched through the documentation and can't find a way to display the icons on a module that I'm creating, has anyone found a way to display them on the direction pane.
How can i search for this driving icon in DirectionsResult object and display it in my JSP..?

Thanks,

Vinayak

Answer (score -1):

The api doesn't give you the icon for each step. You can figure out which icons to show by looking at the instructions text of each step. Strip out the html tags first. Then, if the text starts with "turn right", then use that icon. If it says "keep right", "slight right", "take exit", etc., use the appropriate icon. If it starts with something you don't recognize, don't use an icon.